# Box2d in Cocos2d v3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I started porting game from Cocos2d 2.0 to Cocos2d 3.0. Got compilation error for Box2d.

```
#import <Box2D.h>
b2Body          *mBody;
b2World         *mWorld;
```

What's alternative for this in Cocos2d 3.0 ?

I see only One Cocos2d template, How can I install Cocos2d-Box2d template in Cocos2d 3.0 ?

[image]

Comment: More details. Start by including the actual compiler error message(s) you get and the corresponding lines of code where the error points at.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, I already stated above, for #import Box.2d giving error..here xcode project is new Cocos2d 3.0 and code source file from  cocos2d 2.0, now is there any way to use Box2d in Cocos2d 3.0 ?

Comment: You stated above that you get an error but you did not say **what** error. Your compiler is telling you something, we need to know exactly what it says or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning. It says Box2D.h not found. I think version of cocos2d 3.0 template that I got comes with chipmunk...How can I find box2d cocos2d 3.0 template ?

Comment: Ah yes. There is no Box2D template, it may be coming at a later date but I don't think it has any priority. The physics integration (CCPhysics* classes) is Chipmunk only.

Comment: oh..then let me go back to Cocos2d 2.1 !

Answer (score 1):

Cocos 2D 3 uses Chipmunk as physics engine. It doesn't include box2d template anymore. But you can donwload it separately from https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/list.

Actually the only one thing supported by cocos2d about box2d was the template.

I hope it helps,